# run prolog(.pl) file in with pyswip

Tags: python, swi-prolog

I want to run a prolog file with pyswip and then work with some rules written in that pl file. So far I have only been able to assert a rule, fetching result of an assert in a python list. But how can I run a pl file with pyswip. I have found some documentations, [github](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip/blob/master/test/test_issues.py), [Yuce's Blog](http://yuce.tekol.net/2009/pyswip-facts-and-rules/),   [pyswip page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyswip/)  but none of them implemented what I need.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method **consult** to load a .pl file, with PySWIP:

```
prolog = Prolog()
prolog.consult("myplfile.pl")
```

Hope it helped you!

Comment: then how can i call a predicate of the consulted `prolog` file?

Comment: You can now query the prolog file, regarding the rules and facts that you stated in it. For example:

`prolog.query("father(michael, X)")`